# plotting 2dhistogram with sum value rather than count

Tags: python, matplotlib

Beginner user on the forum. Help please. I have a data set: x, y coordinates, each x, y has a value. I want to plot a 2d histogram displaying the sum of the values in each bin with color scale. matplotlib hexbin is straight forward. I can do this. eg:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

xpos = np.random.rand(0,10)
ypos = np.random.rand(0,10)
plt.hexbin(x = xpos, y = ypos, C=mass, cmap= plt.cm.jet, gridsize=100, reduce_C_function=sum, bins="log")  
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.ax.set_ylabel('log (sum value in each bin)')
plt.xlabel('Xpos')
plt.ylabel('Ypos')
plt.show()
```

However, I'm struggling to make a similar plot with histogram2d or matplotlib hist2d. I think i have to combine binned_statistic_2d and histogram2d somehow. No problem if I replace plt.hexbin line above to this:

```
plt.hist2d(x = xpos, y = ypos, bins = 50, norm = LogNorm())
```

Any clue? I have look on the forum but can't seem to find a working code.

Comment: Whats this supposed to do: `np.random.rand(0,10,0.1)`?

Comment: No. I have a real data set x, y. I see the typos. I'll correct it.

Comment: Just an update. I have solved the problem. Instead of using hist2d, i write my own binning code.

Comment: A possible solution using numpy for binning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777934/creating-a-heatmap-by-sampling-and-bucketing-from-a-3d-array

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the values to show in the binned 2D plot prior to plotting and then show as an `imshow` plot.

If you're happy to use pandas, one option would be to group the mass data accordings to cut (`pandas.cut`) x and y data. Then apply the sum (.sum()) and unstack to obtain a pivot table.

```
df.mass.groupby([pd.cut(df.x, bins=xbins, include_lowest=True), 
                 pd.cut(df.y, bins=ybins, include_lowest=True)]) \
               .sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  matplotlib.colors

xpos = np.random.randint(0,10, size=50)
ypos = np.random.randint(0,10, size=50)
mass = np.random.randint(0,75, size=50)

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":xpos, "y":ypos, "mass":mass})

xbins = range(10)
ybins = range(10)
su = df.mass.groupby([pd.cut(df.x, bins=xbins, include_lowest=True), 
                     pd.cut(df.y, bins=ybins, include_lowest=True)]) \
            .sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print su
im = plt.imshow(su.values, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(1,300))
plt.xticks(range(len(su.index)), su.index, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(range(len(su.columns)), su.columns)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]