# Creating a heatmap by sampling and bucketing from a 3D array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, contourf

I have some experimental data that exists like so:

```
x = array([1, 1.12, 1.109, 2.1, 3, 4.104, 3.1, ...])
y = array([-9, -0.1, -9.2, -8.7, -5, -4, -8.75, ...])
z = array([10, 4, 1, 4, 5, 0, 1, ...])
```

If it's convenient, we can assume that the data exists as a 3D array or even a pandas `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z})
```

The interpretation being, for every position `x[i], y[i]`, the value of some variable is `z[i]`. These are **not evenly sampled**, so there will be some parts that are "densely sampled" (e.g. between 1 and 1.2 in `x`) and others that are very sparse (e.g. between 2 and 3 in `x`). Because of this, I can't just chuck these into a `pcolormesh` or `contourf`.

What I would like to do instead is to resample `x` and `y` evenly at some fixed interval and then aggregate the values of `z`. For my needs, `z` can be summed or averaged to get meaningful values, so this is not a problem. My naïve attempt was like this:

```
X = np.arange(min(x), max(x), 0.1)  
Y = np.arange(min(y), max(y), 0.1)
x_g, y_g = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
nx, ny = x_g.shape
z_g = np.full(x_g.shape, np.nan)

for ix in range(nx - 1):
    for jx in range(ny - 1):
        x_min = x_g[ix, jx]
        x_max = x_g[ix + 1, jx + 1]
        y_min = y_g[ix, jx]
        y_max = y_g[ix + 1, jx + 1]
        vals = df[(df.x >= x_min) & (df.x < x_max) & 
                  (df.y >= y_min) & (df.y < y_max)].z.values
        if vals.any():
            z_g[ix, jx] = sum(vals)
```

This works and I get the output I desire, with `plt.contourf(x_g, y_g, z_g)` but it is SLOW! I have ~20k samples, which I then subsample into ~800 samples in x and ~500 in y, meaning the for loop is 400k long.

Is there any way to vectorize/optimize this? Even better if there is some function that already does this!

(Also tagging this as MATLAB because the syntax between numpy/MATLAB are very similar and I have access to both software.)

Comment: A possible solution in pandas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689070/plotting-2dhistogram-with-sum-value-rather-than-count (although probably not as efficient as the numpy solution below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized Python solution employing [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and `matrix multiplication` with [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for the sum-reduction part -

```
x_mask = ((x >= X[:-1,None]) & (x < X[1:,None]))
y_mask = ((y >= Y[:-1,None]) & (y < Y[1:,None]))

z_g_out = np.dot(y_mask*z[None].astype(np.float32), x_mask.T)

# If needed to fill invalid places with NaNs
z_g_out[y_mask.dot(x_mask.T.astype(np.float32))==0] = np.nan
```

Note that we are avoiding the use of `meshgrid` there. Thus, saving memory there as the meshes created with `meshgrid` would be huge and in the process hopefully gaining performance improvement.

### Benchmarking

```
# Original app
def org_app(x,y,z):    
    X = np.arange(min(x), max(x), 0.1)  
    Y = np.arange(min(y), max(y), 0.1)
    x_g, y_g = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    nx, ny = x_g.shape
    z_g = np.full(np.asarray(x_g.shape)-1, np.nan)

    for ix in range(nx - 1):
        for jx in range(ny - 1):
            x_min = x_g[ix, jx]
            x_max = x_g[ix + 1, jx + 1]
            y_min = y_g[ix, jx]
            y_max = y_g[ix + 1, jx + 1]
            vals = z[(x >= x_min) & (x < x_max) & 
                      (y >= y_min) & (y < y_max)]
            if vals.any():
                z_g[ix, jx] = sum(vals)
    return z_g

# Proposed app
def app1(x,y,z):
    X = np.arange(min(x), max(x), 0.1)  
    Y = np.arange(min(y), max(y), 0.1)
    x_mask = ((x >= X[:-1,None]) & (x < X[1:,None]))
    y_mask = ((y >= Y[:-1,None]) & (y < Y[1:,None]))

    z_g_out = np.dot(y_mask*z[None].astype(np.float32), x_mask.T)

    # If needed to fill invalid places with NaNs
    z_g_out[y_mask.dot(x_mask.T.astype(np.float32))==0] = np.nan
    return z_g_out
```

As seen, for a fair benchmarking, I am using array values with the original approach, as fetching values from a dataframe could slow things down.

Timings and verification -

```
In [143]: x = np.array([1, 1.12, 1.109, 2.1, 3, 4.104, 3.1])
     ...: y = np.array([-9, -0.1, -9.2, -8.7, -5, -4, -8.75])
     ...: z = np.array([10, 4, 1, 4, 5, 0, 1])
     ...: 

# Verify outputs
In [150]: np.nansum(np.abs(org_app(x,y,z) - app1(x,y,z)))
Out[150]: 0.0

In [145]: %timeit org_app(x,y,z)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.9 ms per loop

In [146]: %timeit app1(x,y,z)
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.1 µs per loop

In [147]: 19900/39.1  # Speedup figure
Out[147]: 508.95140664961633
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MATLAB solution:

```
X = min(x)-1 :.1:max(x)+1; % the grid needs to be expanded slightly beyond the min and max
Y = min(y)-1 :.1:max(y)+1;
x_o = interp1(X, 1:numel(X), x, 'nearest');
y_o = interp1(Y, 1:numel(Y), y, 'nearest');
z_g = accumarray([x_o(:) y_o(:)], z(:),[numel(X) numel(Y)]);
```